# Omit array of keys with Underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

Using Underscore (technically Lodash).  Have an object that looks like the following.

```
var myObj = {
    first: {name: 'John', occupation: 'Welder', age: 30},
    second: {name: 'Tim', occupation: 'A/C Repair', kids: true},
    third: {name: 'Dave', occupation: 'Electrician', age: 32},
    fourth: {name: 'Matt', occupation: 'Plumber', age: 41, kids: false}
};
```

I also have a hash of arrays that I want to "clean" out of each object:

```
var excludes = {
    first: ['name', 'age'],
    second: ['occupation'],
    fourth: ['kids]
};
```

The idea is that each of the elements in the array will be dropped from the object that has the matching key.  Meaning my data will end up like this:

```
{
    first: {occupation: 'Welder'},
    second: {name: 'Tim', kids: true},
    third: {name: 'Dave', occupation: 'Electrician', age: 32},
    fourth: {name: 'Matt', occupation: 'Plumber', age: 41}
};
```

I was originally trying:

```
_.map(myObj, function(obj, k) {
    if(_.has(excludes, k) {
        // not sure what here
    }
});
```

I was thinking of using omit at the innermost level, but I can only drop one key at a time, not a list of keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, [`_.omit`](https://lodash.com/docs#omit) can take a list of keys:

```
result = _.transform(myObj, function(result, val, key) {
    result[key] = _.omit(val, excludes[key]);
});
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I misread `(string|string[])` in the docs, didn't realize that meant it took an array of strings.